# rails 3 query with count on nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Consider I have 3 tables: Users (has_many) -> Websites (has_many) -> Visits.
How would one find out the total number of Visits each user has without writing plain sql code?

I have an idea of which I'm not very proud since I let rails do the math instead of mysql:

```
count = 0
user.websites.each |website|
    count += website.visits.count()
```

I'm new with rails and maybe i'm missing some docs. Is it possible to find out that count just from the query builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define that the User has many Visits through the Websites like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :websites
  has_many :visits, :through => :websites
end
```

now, if you do

> some_user.visits.count

this sql is executed:

```
(0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "visits" INNER JOIN "websites" ON "visits"."website_id" = "websites"."id" WHERE "websites"."user_id" = 1
=> 8
```

That is, ActiveRecord creates the SQL query for you.